# Meu post sumiu. Será um gasparzinho?

Tags: debate

Fiz um post aí, sobre problema de lógica e fui ver se havia resposta, simplesmente não aparec para mim. O que aconteceu? Alguém sabe? Não postei palavrões, nem nada. Já resetei a minha máquina e ainda continuo não vendo-o. Uma explicação, por favor, de quem sabe o que aconteceu.

Comment: Tens a URL no histórico do browser? Aparece em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/6420 ? Só você, ou moderadores, podem ver esse link.

Comment: Esta apenas é uma indicação para um próxima pergunta no mesmo estilo do mesmo usuário, por mais que não seja necessário (como eu sei q não é) isso provavelmente vai ajuda-lo, já que aparentemente ele é um usuário interessado no SOPT

Comment: @ErlonCharles, é só questão de seguir o procedimento correto: não devemos promover que um usuário duplique sua pergunta em outro site da rede [se]. Se a pergunta é migrável, vote como tal e avise o usuário. Se não, explique a diferença e peça pra ler o que é *on-topic* ([help/on-topic]) em cada site ;)

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi nada do que vocês estão falando, verdade. O link acima quando eu abro diz que não há nenhuma pergunta deletada.

Comment: @pnet, só meu primeiro comentário é relevante ao problema. Os outros dois são à respeito do funcionamento do site. Se você não tem um link que a gente possa tentar rastrear, só esperando que alguém com acesso administrativo analise o caso...

Comment: Para o autor da pergunta provavelmente não irá mais servir(vide data da pergunta) mas uma orientação para quem passar por uma situação similar é de imediatamente vasculhar o histórico do navegador em busca do link da pergunta desaparecida e informar o desaparecimento junto desse esse link a moderação.